# How to obtain an event firing for everytime PopUpManager.removePopup is invoked?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

Fairly straight-forward... I want to do something along the lines of listenening for an event that would fire every time "PopUpManager.removePopUp" is called. I wasn't able to find any events around this. Every popup I'm creating is by using PopUpManager's createPopup function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this isn't in line with the original question but this is what I wound up doing:

As part of PopUpManager's createPopup function, they allow you to pass in a child list string for it to be added to. By using PopUpManagerChildList.POPUP as my parameter, I'm able to obtain a list of popups that are currently open using sysManager.popUpChildren.numChildren to determine how many were showing so long as I used that parameter in all of my createPopup calls.

Answer (score 0):

Not to sure IF I understand this the right way, but if you use the code like this in your pop up window???

............................

showCloseButton="true"

```
close="closeWindow(event)">

<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        import mx.events.CloseEvent;
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;
        import mx.core.IFlexDisplayObject;

        private function closeWindow(e:CloseEvent):void {

            PopUpManager.removePopUp(e.target as IFlexDisplayObject);
        }

    ]]>
</mx:Script>
```